# Using JSONB in rails 6 forms and permitted params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jsonb, ruby-on-rails-6, activemodel

I am trying to use JSONB in a deeply tested form that works

```
<%= simple_form_for(@company, local: true) do |form| %>
  <%= form.simple_fields_for @schedule do |ff| %>
        <%= ff.select :status, Schedule.statuses.keys.collect {
           |status| [Schedule.human_enum_name(:status, status), status] },
            class:"custom-control", label: false %>
         <%= ff.date_field :valid_from     %>
         <%= ff.date_field :valid_through  %>
               <%= ff.simple_fields_for :business_hours do |field| %>
                   <% I18n.t('date.day_names').each_with_index do |day, wday| %>
                      <%= field.label :"#{day.downcase}" %></td>
                      <%= field.select :"#{day.downcase}_closes_at",
                                        collection: time_select_options,
                                        class: 'custom-select',
                                        include_blank: "Closed" %>
                      <%= field.select :"#{day.downcase}_closes_at",
                                        collection: time_select_options,
                                        class: 'custom-select',
                                        include_blank: "Closed" %>

         <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The nested business_hours field is the JSONB col.

The Schedule model belongs_to Company, which has_may Schedules.I am using store_accessor :business_hours in the Schedule model.

Schedule model looks like:

```
  has_many :schedules, inverse_of: :company, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :schedules, allow_destroy: true,
   reject_if: proc { |att| att["day"].blank? }
```

the Company controller is set as follows:

```
  def new
    @account = current_account
    @company = @account.company.new
    @chedule = @company.schedules.new

  end

  def create
    @account = current_account
    @company = @account.build_company(company_params)
    @company.save
  end

  def edit
    @schedules = @company.schedules.all
  end

  def update
    @company.update(company_params)
  end
```

i am whitelisting with

```
def company_params
    params.require(:company).permit(:name, ...,
      ...,
      schedules_attributes: [:status, :id, :_destroy, :day, :valid_from, :valid_through,
              business_hours: [:sunday_opens_at, ...]
end
```

the form submit as follows:

```
Processing by CompaniesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"...", "company"=>{"schedule"=>{"status"=>"active", "valid_from"=>"2020-06-01", "valid_through"=>"2020-06-01", "business_hours"=>{"monday_closes_at"=>"00:00:00", "tuesday_closes_at"=>"00:00:00", ...}}}, "button"=>"", "locale"=>"en", "id"=>"acme-sas"}
```

however I receive: Unpermitted parameter: :schedule

Comment: Did you use `accept_nested_attributes`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the review.  Yes I have accept_nested_attributes. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

you need to send schedule as schedules
 
`Processing by CompaniesController#update as HTMLParameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"...", "company"=>{"schedules"=>{"status"=>"active", "valid_from"=>"2020-06-01", "valid_through"=>"2020-06-01", "business_hours"=>{"monday_closes_at"=>"00:00:00", "tuesday_closes_at"=>"00:00:00", ...}}}, "button"=>"", "locale"=>"en", "id"=>"acme-sas"}`